# Ubuntu 12 installation - partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition

I want to install Ubuntu 12 and I would like to partition my hard drive so that the OS lives in its own partition and the data in a different one. Thus if the system breaks for some reason, the data will remain intact. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Although it's a fantastic idea to separate `/` and `/home` it's not enough. You need a backup solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend, especially since you're not an advanced user, a separate /home, as above, and periodical backup to optical media: cheap, easy and somewhat reliable. If you really have important data, I would think of something else, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the following because from a single HDD if that has a hardware problem it doesn't matter what your partition table looks like.

1. Put data on an external HW Raid array.
2. Backup Solutions because things happen.

On top of this there are a few [Partitioning Best Practice](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/aunix1/partitioning.htm) guides like the one I linked which you may want to take a look at.

Comment: I don't think RAID is necessary for the ordinary home user. A backup solution is all that's needed.

Comment: @Marco May be not but separating data physically is.  Most problems with HDDs on Linux are not partition related but the underlying hardware, which will kill the OS and the data partition together without the separation.

Comment: Thank you guys. I need something basic. Wht is HW Raid array and what's HDD?

Comment: HDD = Hard Disk Drive, HW Raid is Hardware Based RAID solution like: http://www.amazon.com/G-Technology-G-RAID-Dual-External-Drive/dp/B002QID2NG/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1362583962&sr=8-1&keywords=raid+array

Comment: I have a laptop I don't need fancy things.. a working solution. What do all folks do when they want to install a new Linux version?

Comment: @saadtaame In the case of a laptop it makes no difference.  Biggest problems are physical problems with HDDs so having one or multiple partitions won't help in this case.  The only thing that you will be able to do to insure recoverability is having good backups.

Comment: @Karlson In that case I'll be thankful if you could tell me what are best practices when it comes to backup.

Comment: @saadtaame You should open a separate question for that.  Plus you should consider mentioning what it is that you're trying to back up.